# Magento - Buy X Get Y Free - Realistically, Buy one get one free BOGOF

Tags: magento, shopping-cart

I have successfully setup a shopping cart rule to allow a user to purchase 2 products and get the third free. I used the "Buy X Get Y Free" option and have inserted '1' into the Discount Amount field and inserted '2' into the Discount Qty Step.

I have decided to even further entice my offer and allow the user to purchase only 1 product and get the second free. But when I update the Discount Qty Step to '1', the shopping cart is not even running any type of discounts, no matter what qty of products I have in my cart.

Am I completely missing the boat on this or can someone please explain to me how I can successfully run a 1:1 ratio on the Buy X Get Y Free option in the Shopping Cart Rules.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Seems more of a question for the author of the coupon module thana programming question.  But good luck regardless! ;)

Comment: Maybe the site cron isn't running properly to update the price rules.

Answer (score 4):

For whatever reason you can't do BOGO like that. Under "Actions" you have to change "Apply" to "Percent of product price discount" and then enter "50" into the "Discount" box. Set "Discount Qty Step" to "2". That be a feasible workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.
but there is only one restriction that is , it not work with onestep check out.

http://blog.gaiterjones.com/free-magento-extension-buy-one-get-one-free-discounted/